# iOS CoreAudio - using AUFilePlayer and a render callback

Tags: ios, core-audio

just started developing a small test iOS 5.0 app to see what is possible on the platform.

Some ressources were unvaluable, for example Chris Adamson's blog, and David Zicarelli's audioGraph example (based upon Apple's MixerHost with a bunch of new features).

What I'm trying to do is to setup something like this, using the new FilePlayer AudioUnit from the iOS 5.x SDK.

(AUFilePlayer bus0) -> (some custom process) -> (bus0 MultiChannelMixer bus0) -> (bus0 Remote I/O)

I started with audioGraph, removed what I didn't want, and ended up with the above chain.

I could see that AUFilePlayer preferred output is a 8.24 streams, so the mixer is also setup that way (8.24 on input scope). My process will handle any conversion it will need.

The "custom process" callback is registered for the mixer on bus 0. Once the app is launched, it gets called regularly, which I could verify by logging.

```
static OSStatus simpleRenderCallback (
                                  void *inRefCon, 
                                  AudioUnitRenderActionFlags  
                                  *ioActionFlags, 
                                  const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp,  
                                  UInt32  inBusNumber,   
                                  UInt32  inNumberFrames,  
                                  AudioBufferList *ioData
                                  ) {
MixerHostAudio* THIS = (MixerHostAudio*) inRefCon; //the MixerHostAudio instance

AudioUnit fpUnit= THIS.auFilePlayerUnit_1;


OSStatus renderErr = noErr;



renderErr= AudioUnitRender(AUFilePlayerUnit, ioActionFlags, inTimeStamp, 0, inNumberFrames, ioData); 
if (renderErr < 0) {
    NSLog(@"error:%ld",renderErr);
    return renderErr;
}


return noErr;
}
```

The issue is that I'm always getting a renderErr = -50 each time the AudioUnitRender gets called in my callback.

I'm running with the simulator for now, the Mac soundcard is set to 44,100Hz, and I could see that the inNumberFrames is always equal to 512.

Where does the problem come from? -50 means "bad param" in CoreAudio, but that's not enough to know what's wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: As you point out -50 is `paramErr`.  Have you verified in the debugger that each parameter to `AudioUnitRender` is correct and what you expect?

Comment: Yes, each parameter was correct. But it seems that my error was with ABSD (the usual suspect!) which AUFilePlayer wouldn't accept on iOS. Come on Apple, please document these "new" AudioUnits! Once the stream description was properly set (mono Float32 stream, oddly), it would spit out samples as expected. I have another problem, but that's for another question I guess. Thanks!